# "X questions with new activity" notification now triggering for ignored tags

Tags: bug, ignored-tags, live-refresh, homepage

Starting two or three days ago, I've noticed the "Questions with new activity" notification has started appearing for questions with tags that I'm ignoring. After clicking the notification, no new questions appear for me.

While this would occasionally happen before, it is now happening with consistency, always showing the notification when an ignored question receives new activity.