# “X questions with new activity” showing incorrect information in windows with multiple tag filters

Tags: bug, live-refresh, filtering, regression

Recently (in the past week or so) I have noticed that windows in which I have multiple tag filters in effect -- say [serialization](/questions/tagged/serialization) + [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) -- the `X questions with new activity` banner will give wrong information, and when clicked on will generate wrong results.  Only by reloading the window can I get a correctly filtered set of questions.

Details as follows.

Earlier today on Stack Overflow I opened a window for all questions tagged with `[serialization]` and `[c#]`, newest first:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialization%2bc%23?tab=Newest

After a couple hours I noticed there were **41** new questions:

[image]

So I clicked on the `41 questions with new activity` banner -- and a bunch of questions appeared matching [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) **but not [serialization](/questions/tagged/serialization)**:

[image]

I then reloaded the page and found that, actually, there were no new questions at all matching both tags:

[image]

As the newest question in the list, [Select SQL Server DatetimeOffset as .Net DateTimeOffset.Ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60238049/3744182), was completely unmodified today according to its [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60238049/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries).

However, in windows with just a single tag filter, say [`[.net]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), the banner does appear to give correct information.

Somehow the filtering logic is getting wrongly applied when showing results in the `X questions with new activity` banner.  This appears to be a regression from *[When I search for certain tags, the "X new questions with update" comes up only one one of the tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128126/344280)* (from 2012) for which the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128225/344280) states:

> After the next deploy we will support both the AND and the OR operators on tags for realtime updates which will fix this issue...

My impression is that it started happening within the past week or so.

Note: possible duplicates include:

- *["X questions with new activity" notification now triggering for ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343756/344280)*.
- *[Has the behaviour of combined tags search changed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393969/3744182)* on MSO.
- *[Recent fix broke AND-OR queries; cf "nn questions with new activity"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394046/3744182)* on MSO.

Comment: This bug is still there and apparently also network-wide. This needs to be given some serious priority! Viewing a site by selecting tags is kind of the very core of the whole network.